# Apache ignore missing DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration

I would like to configure my apache different. Now, if one of DocumentRoots is missing, all server fail to start. That's annoying..

Is there any option, how to ignore this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the assumption that your DocumentRoot directive is used synonomously with a VirtualHost, you could separate the VirtualHosts configuration into separate conf files, place these individually into their document roots and then include them with a directory wide include directive in a generic, serverwide conf. See below for an example:

Create a conf in the directory below:

```
/etc/apache/sites-enabled/sites.conf
```

add the following

```
Include /data/www/sites/
```

This will include any conf file in the above directory and any subdirectory

For a host with the following DocumentRoot

```
/data/www/sites/website-one
```

Create a VirtualHost conf file and place it in the above directory e.g:

/data/www/sites/website-one/website-one.conf

And your conf file will contain all the information about the VirtualHost including the DocumentRoot e.g

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /data/www/sites/website-one
ServerName www.website-one.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

If the DocumentRoot doesn't exist, then the conf file doesn't get loaded and the DocumentRoot directive never executed. For security reasons be careful that your conf files don't become dereferenceable. This should probably be disabled at a server level, but it is something to be aware of. Finally, the above pattern means that any bad conf files in the `/data/www/sites` directory and subdirectories will cause the server not to start.